# Two seperate divs, why is one rendering inside the other?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, shopify

[html before rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSPfL.png)

So for a start I am coding a store in shopify using their timber framework which utilizes a css wizardry responsive grid.

As you can see in the image there is a grid, and one div that is supposed to span one quarter, and another that is supposed to span 3 quarters.

Now when viewing the page, the 3/4 width div renders inside the 1/4 div instead of after it. As seen here:
[html after rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlFsw.png)

This makes absolutely no sense and I don't see why this would happen, because if I swap them around so that the 3/4 width div comes before the one quarter width div, they both render fine and independently, why is this happening?

Comment: please include code snippets instead of pictures of code, I can't test a picture.

Comment: As said above, can you post native code?
It might come from a conditionnal Liquid statement but impossible to say without code.

Answer (score 1):

Are all of the html tags correctly closed?
I suggest you viewing the code source of your html page instead of inspecting it with a browser developer tool for viewing the uninterpreted DOM tree.